# Dealing with multiple imageview data

Tags: android, imageview

I'm a newbie in Android development.

I currently don't have any code to show but I need help with the logic for my idea/project.

So here is the scenario:

I have 3 empty Imageview:

```
ImgView1
ImgView2
ImgView3
```

If I want to add an image, the image should be inserted to ImgView3, and if I add another, it should be inserted to ImgView2 and so for so on.

Now my problem is:

When I want to delete the image in ImgView3, the image in the ImgView2 should be transfered in the ImgView3.

Just like this:

[Transferring the image from ImgView2 to ImgView3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNeSH.png)

And the ImgView1 image should transfer to ImgView2:

[ImgView1 to ImgView2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9xVD.png)

So in the end:

- ImgView1 - No image
- ImgView2 - Has image
- ImgView3 - Has image

There's also another scenario, Let's assume that all imageview have images.

If the User deleted image in the ImgView2, the ImgView1 should transfer its image to ImgView2.

I currently don't have the code right now because I'm working on its logic.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far

Comment: Stop thinking in terms of imgView1, imgView2, imgView3 but in terms of arrays. If you dispose on imageView referenced in the array, and remove that element from the array you won't even get into a situation where you would move bitmaps around different imageViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part try this logic:

```
onAdd(Bitmap bitmap)
{
  if (ImgView3.getBitmap == null)
      {
        ImagView3.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
  else
      {
        if(ImgView2.getBitmap == null)
           {
               ImagView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           }
           else
           {
              if(ImgView1.getBitmap == null)
                 {
                     ImagView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 }
           }
      }
}
```

For deletion:

```
DeleteFirstImage()
{
  ImgView3.setImageBitmap(null);
  if(ImgView3.getBitmap() == null)
  {
    ImgView3.setImageBitmap(ImgView2.getBitmap());
    ImgView2.setImageBitmap(null);
    if(ImgView2.getBitmap() == null)
    {
      ImgView2.setImageBitmap(ImgView1.getBitmap());
      ImgView1.setImageBitmap(null);
      if(imagView1.getBitmap == null)
      {
         //Do nothing, this is OK :)
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Create DeleteSecondImage() in a similar way and also the DeleteFirstImage()

Comment: This is splendid!, i also thought about this way, but i was thinking if i can do it in the loop e.g do(while) , for loop and etc. i can consider this but i'll wait for more better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you started (I haven't tested it, I just quickly made it)

First, create an array of your ImageViews:

```
private ImageView[] imageViews = new ImageView[]{mImageView1, mImageView2, mImageView3};
```

Here's the set method:

```
private void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        for (int i = imageViews.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViews[i];
            if (imageView.getDrawable() == null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Here's the Delete method:

```
private void deleteBitmap(int position) {
        ImageView imageViewToDelete = imageViews[position];

        if (imageViewToDelete.getDrawable() == null) {
            // We don't have anything here, so return
            return;
        }

        for (int i = position; i >= 0; i--) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViews[i];
            imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

            if (i != 0) {
                ImageView previousImage = imageViews[i - 1];
                if (previousImage.getDrawable() != null) {
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) previousImage.getDrawable()
                    if (bitmapDrawable != null) {
                        Bitmap previousBitmap =  bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(previousBitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is what i'm looking for! , i'll let you know if it works. Thanks for this. I'll update you if i encounter any problem.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the setBitmap, i tried to do it imageView[0].setImageBitmap and it worked, i do that just to check if the image is being passed on. i think there's something wrong with the loop. i'll let you know if i can solve it.

Comment: ah got it, in for loops there should be i-- instead of i++

Comment: fixed it , it should be :i >= 0; i--, i'll let you know tomorrow if i encounter any problem about delete. thanks again. i'll mark this as answer as soon as i'm finish.

Comment: you are right, it should be i >=0 as well. Actually I was first trying the reverse way then changed the logic but forgot to change the for loop part :-/

Comment: It's ok, you can edit your post so that other people wont experience the error. anyway. i'll update you as soon as i can. Thanks again!. You are awesome!

Comment: i added 3 images and then deleted all of them and i tried to add images again but it seems like i can't add images anymore. ahm.

Comment: If image are not being added afterwards, the only thing can be is image.getDrawable is not returning true. You'll need to debug further where it's breaking

Comment: When i try to add an image and it will going to be put in imgView3, then when i try to delete imgView3, error prompts up. ahm.

Comment: You'll need to check logs why it crashes or what it does. I don't have the setup to test this currently. I have tried to assume what problem could be and edited my ans. Try to check that. I fear I won't be able to do much here now :)